# How to update listview row on updation of its content string in database?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, updatemodel

I have two listviews which are exactly same. I am using one listview to update the containing string. I am using below query to update database.

myDatabase.update(TABLE_WORKSITEFOLDER, contentValues, KEY_LOCALID + " = ? ", new String[] { String.valueOf(increementedCurrentPosition)});

My database gets updated but the listview(s) row which contains this string doesn't get updated. Is this achieved by updating the list adapter. If so then How to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Two problems.

1. String literals need to be quoted in single quotes as addressed by many other answers. Consider using `?` placeholders and bind arguments, though.
2. Use `execSQL()` and not `rawQuery()` for SQL like this. `rawQuery()` just compiles the SQL but doesn't run it. It is only run when the cursor is moved. `execSQL()` both compiles and runs the SQL.

Example:

```
myDatabase.execSQL("UPDATE " + TABLE_WORKFLOW + " SET " + KEY_NAME + " = ? WHERE " + KEY_LOCALID + " = ?",
    new Object[] { updatedName, increementedCurrentPosition });
```

Comment: I upvote this because I was convinced that `rawQuery` runs query, but it also returns result set. `execSQL` is exactly for insert or update. So you helped me to clarify this :)

Comment: Your query runs perfectly and database is updated accordingly but the listview rows which contains these strings are not updated, i.e, they are showing without updated string. How to update my list view following an updation in the database.

Comment: Depends on your adapter. Generally, update the adapter and call `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. put update string in single quote

```
 UPDATE WorkFlow SET Name = '131568.0010 – EcoGreenWatch.org vs. Northern Plains Oil, Inc.12345' WHERE LocalId = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The database field value is TEXT, need to add ' '

try it code :

```
myDatabase.rawQuery("UPDATE " + TABLE_WORKFLOW + " SET " + KEY_NAME + " = '" + updatedName + "' WHERE " + KEY_LOCALID + " = " + increementedCurrentPosition, null);
```

Comment: trying your answer would run my query smoothly but i dont get the updated string in the listview from where it was edited.

Comment: i don't understand you purpose ,maybe you need to update ListView adapter, call  mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: I have checked my database by running the app on emulator but the database row is not updated.

Comment: check you increementedCurrentPosition field value is exists.

Comment: try this code  myDatabase.rawQuery("UPDATE ? SET  ? = ? WHERE ? = ?", new String[]{TABLE_WORKFLOW,KEY_NAME,updatedName,KEY_LOCALID increementedCurrentPosition.toString()});

Comment: i am already selecting the data in listview but with reference to another column value in the table.

Comment: sorry ,this Missing a , KEY_LOCALID ,increementedCurrentPosition.toString()

Comment: Now i am getting this error:        android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "?": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: UPDATE ? SET ? = ? WHERE ? = ?

Comment: i'm sorry,RawQuery() can only be used to query, execSQL() can do update and insert,change you method , see  @laalto  resolution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68467/discussion-between-hoafer-and-ashish-kumar-gupta).

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be:

```
myDatabase.rawQuery("UPDATE " + TABLE_WORKFLOW + " SET '" + KEY_NAME + "' = " + updatedName + " WHERE " + KEY_LOCALID + " = " + increementedCurrentPosition, null);
```

I.e. KEY_NAME is inside single quotes because it is TEXT type.